# How to see the unsettled transaction in Authorize.net?

Tags: payment-gateway, authorize.net

I got the email for the transaction .But I cant see my transaction in my account.How can I see it in the authorize.net site?

Comment: This is a better question for the Authorize.net support people to help you with.

Answer (score 0):

Log into your Authorize.Net account and then click on the "unsettled transactions" link. Yes, it's that easy. :)

Comment: I already checked.Whether the problem with new API?Bcoz I am using the six months old class written for Authorize.net

Comment: I doubt it's the class since it doesn't affect Authnet's logging of transaction. Are you in test mode? Or using a developer account?